Google choose to index category pages instead of the company page
My website is a directory of companies.
I have the companies, and some directories (by zip code and starting letter) to allow google to get to the company page.
I have a sitemap which includes only companies, there is a canonical tag on the company page too. The pagination is implemented with rel=next/prev.
For some reason, 3 weeks ago the sitemaps are no longer displayed in the sitemap index (no sitemaps displayed, they were fine before), most of the companies were removed from Google (with status Crawled currently not indexed), while directories are still there.

I have a few website like this. They start fine, google goes through sitemaps and indexes companies, I get clicks and impressions.
As soon as google gets to directories and indexes them, the website sinks (-90% in clicks) and never recovers.
Is there a way to tell google which pages are important and which one are not ?
Maybe someone else had this issue ?

Google decides on its own which pages are important.  This is based on (amongst other factors)

How many times the page is referenced within the site
How many external sites refer to the page
The content is substantial and is consistent with the title, header etc.
The content is substantially unique as compared to other pages on your site

I would suggest that you do not index the letter pages as it makes no sense why people would want to search for them. And these pages have no real unique content.  I refer to Companies starting with the letter 'A'.
You can do this by using the meta tag
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">

